# XAMPP Virtual host for running PHP sersvices

Tags: php, apache, rest, xampp

I am asking this question as after a two days of research I could not setup what I am trying to. Below is what I am trying to do:

I have a PHP project where I have my HTMLs (templates) and PHP REST services in different folders

```
-- templates
-- api
```

What I am trying to do is deploy my REST services on a different PORT or a VIRTUALHOST so that I can test these services using Postman and also use them AJAX calls. I have been able to access the services directly using the relative URL, but I wanted to have them available on a different URL.

Running the services using the PHP's built in web server I am able to access them but I want to do the same using Apache. I will have to replicate the same on my shared hosting also.

```
php -S 127.0.0.1:8000 -t public
```

I am not sure if I am doing the right thing and need some advise to achieve what I am trying to do.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like the way I asked the question was not right. I was able to fix this issue by .htaccess file and making some code fixes. Please leave a comment if you any one needs a detailed answer.